# Dynamic variable for custom component functions in Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder

I define a variable which is dynamicaly changes based on the user interactions, for example ID of an object sets to variable when user touches on it. After the ID sets I call a function in a custom component which is related to that object. Like this;

activeObject.videoPlay(event)  ---> if the activeObject is video1 --->  video1.videoPlay(event) function will be called.

I tried several variable types when defining the variable activeObject, such as String , Array but didnt work out. By the way the data set to variable is String. When I use String type it gives this error;

Error #1061: Call to a possibly undefined method videoPlay through a reference with static type String.

Is there any way to use a string as a dynamic variable?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to use a string as a dynamic variable?

Bracket notation --  obj["dynamicPropertyName"] as Type or in your case (activeObject['videoPlay'] as Function).apply(abc, [event]);  You'll obviously want null object checks etc.